# Wordpress Site From Windows Server to Linux Server

Tags: asp.net, linux, wordpress

I was recently hired as webmaster at this company. It is hosted on the windows asp.net framework and my boss wants to move it to a Linux server. I have read that it is a pain to transfer  sites between .NET and Linux because of the different languages the two servers use, but the site in question is a wordpress.org site and so all the back end files are in PHP. Since it appears that none of the files use the .NET language, will it still be a problem to transfer the site to a linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to transfer the wordpress site, no.  Just get the mysql dump of the database and get the install directory for wordpress and copy it over.

You'll have to modify the config files a little bit depending on the destination server's mysql (connection info for example).

I just did this recently and wordpress is very simple for doing a site transfer.